# Unstable Bloomberg connection

Tags: python, connection, spyder, bloomberg, blpapi

I use Spyder 5.1.5, Python 3.9.12 and Blpapi 3.17.1. I have used Bloomberg data to calculate a Fear and Greed index for a while but now it doesn't work. I manage to get some data from bloomberg but after a while the bloomberg connection ends. The program is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import blpapi as blpapi
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Read as Read_Excel
#from IPython import get_ipython

startdate = '19980101'
enddate=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
 
sec_list=[]
sec_list.append('SPXT Index')
sec_list.append('lt11truu index')
sec_list.append('pcrttotl index')
sec_list.append('vix index')
sec_list.append('sum inx index')
sec_list.append('nwhlnyhl index')
sec_list.append('csi barc index')
sec_list.append('biclb10y index')

#************************************
def bbhist(full_ticker,fields,startdate,enddate,setting_list=
           [["periodicitySelection","DAILY"],["nonTradingDayFillMethod","PREVIOUS_VALUE"],["nonTradingDayFillOption","ALL_CALENDAR_DAYS"],
            ["periodicityAdjustment","ACTUAL"]]):
    '''Full ticker example: ERICA SS Equity'''
    if type(full_ticker) is list:
        full_ticker_list=full_ticker
    else:
        full_ticker_list=[]
        full_ticker_list.append(full_ticker)
    
    if type(fields) is list:
        field_list=fields
    else:
        field_list=[]
        field_list.append(fields)
    
    session = blpapi.Session()
    session.start()
    session.openService("//blp/refdata")
    service = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
    request = service.createRequest("HistoricalDataRequest")
    for ticker in full_ticker_list:
        request.getElement("securities").appendValue(ticker)
    
    for field in field_list:
        request.getElement("fields").appendValue(field)
    for setting in setting_list:
        request.set(setting[0], setting[1])
    
    request.set("startDate", startdate)
    request.set("endDate", enddate)
    request.set("maxDataPoints", 1000000)
    request.set("pricingOption","PRICING_OPTION_PRICE") #PX_BID always Clean Price and not yield. "PRICING_OPTION_YIELD"
    
    session.sendRequest(request)
    endReached = False
    df_list=[]
    while endReached == False:
        ev = session.nextEvent()
        if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE or ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE:
            for msg in ev:
                #print(msg)
                sec_name=msg.getElement('securityData').getElementAsString('security')
                fieldDataArray=msg.getElement('securityData').getElement('fieldData')
                size = fieldDataArray.numValues()
                fieldDataList = [fieldDataArray.getValueAsElement(i) for i in range(0,size)]
                outDates = [x.getElementAsDatetime('date') for x in fieldDataList]
                dftempoutput = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Ticker']+field_list)
                dftempoutput['Date']=outDates
                dftempoutput['Ticker']=sec_name
                for fld in field_list:
                    outData = [x.getElementAsFloat(fld) if x.hasElement(fld) else pd.np.nan for x in fieldDataList]
                    dftempoutput[fld] = outData
            df_list.append(dftempoutput)
        if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
            endReached = True
    dfOutPut=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df_list])
    dfOutPut.replace('#N/A History',pd.np.nan,inplace=True)
    #dfOutPut.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
    return dfOutPut
#***************************************************
first = True
for i in sec_list:    
    data_1 = bbhist(i,'PX_LAST', startdate, enddate, setting_list = [])
```

I get the following error:

```
 Input In [169] in <cell line: 98>
    data_1 = bbhist(i,'PX_LAST', startdate, enddate, setting_list = [])

  Input In [169] in bbhist
    request = service.createRequest("HistoricalDataRequest")

  File ~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\blpapi\service.py:383 in createRequest
    _ExceptionUtil.raiseOnError(errCode)

  File ~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\blpapi\exception.py:146 in raiseOnError
    _ExceptionUtil.raiseException(errorCode, description)

  File ~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\blpapi\exception.py:138 in raiseException
    raise errorClass(description, errorCode)

InvalidArgumentException: Null service handle (0x00020002)
```

Comment: I have checked that bbcomm.exe is running from port 8194 and that I am retrieving data from that port.

Comment: Maybe try supplying some options to the `Session()` constructor: https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/python/3.18/_autosummary/blpapi.SessionOptions.html
eg `setAutoRestartOnDisconnection()`. Also perhaps process the Session status events that are sent after the `start()` function: they will tell you if anything is amiss with the start-up. Maybe also a `stop()` call on the session at the end of the function too?

Comment: I have tried with sessionOptions.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(autoRestart=True) but it doesn't help. I can see that bbcomm.exe is running on port 8194 but that session.start() generate False so somehow they don't find each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but provides a diagnostic method to help identify why the session is not starting correctly:

```
import blpapi

def processStatusMessages(sess):
    while True:
        evt = sess.tryNextEvent()

        if evt is None:
            break

        print("EventType:",evt.eventType())  

        for msg in evt:
            print(msg)

sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.setServerHost('localhost')
sessionOptions.setServerPort(8194)
sessionOptions.setNumStartAttempts(1)
sessionOptions.setConnectTimeout(1000)
sessionOptions.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(True)

session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

bStarted = session.start()
processStatusMessages(session)

if bStarted:
    session.openService('//blp/refdata')
    svc = session.getService('//blp/refdata')
    processStatusMessages(session)

    #create a request etc

    session.stop()
```

The output should be something like:

```
EventType: 2
SessionConnectionUp = {
    server = "localhost:8194"
    encryptionStatus = "Clear"
    compressionStatus = "Uncompressed"
}

EventType: 2
SessionStarted = {
    initialEndpoints[] = {
        initialEndpoints = {
            address = "localhost:8194"
        }
    }
}

EventType: 9
CID: {[ valueType=AUTOGEN classId=0 value=1 ]}
RequestId: a4b41e5e-0ad0-1b56-0000-38ea060a0500
ServiceOpened = {
    serviceName = "//blp/refdata"
}
```

Depending on the latency of your network you could try bumping up the connection timeout.

Most implementations I have seen create a single session instance at global scope and re-use it (and possibly the service instance too). Opening and closing sessions is a relatively expensive process (and takes resources on both the client and the server). It may be that the Bloomberg servers are baulking at repeated opening & closing of sessions.

*However*, unless you have a reason not to, I would suggest trying the `xbbg` Python package. It wraps the low-level `blpapi` functions and handles all the error and message processing eg provides a `bdh()` function which is the equivalent of your `bbhist()`.

Comment: When I look at the bbcomm.log  i find the following text "2022/10/06 13:58:36.930 [WARN ] (5724.9552) server: MaxConnections REACHED!" I appreciate if anyone has any idea of what I should make of this?

Comment: @Ulf Are you surprised? Your code creates Session objects but doesn't explicitly free them up, so it is not surprising that you exceed a limit for concurrent Sessions (you aren't Bloomberg's only user needing access to the server). As I mentioned in my answer, most applications only have one Session instance and re-use it, as continually opening and closing sessions takes a lot of resource for both client and server. Make the Session and Service objects global variables, and only intitialize them once in your program.

Comment: I managed to solve it. The problem consisted - as you correctly understood - that I opened the bloomberg session several times. I changed therefore the program (which worked earlier) and put the opening of the session to the programs constructor. That did the trick. Thank's for the help.